# How to construct a space-filling curve in the first place

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

My question is based on Baby Rudin Exercise 7.14.
Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ be an even, 2-periodic fn: $f(t)=f(-t)$ and $f(t+2)=f(t)$ $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Let
$$f(t)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } t \in [0,\frac{1}{3}] \\
3t-1 & \text{if } t \in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}] \\
1 & \text{if } t \in (\frac{2}{3},1]
\end{cases}$$ Then f is clearly cont, and this in fact specifies its values on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  Now let
$$g(t)=(g_1(t),g_2(t)):=(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(3^{2k-2}t)}{2^k}, \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(3^{2k-1}t)}{2^k})$$Then $g:[0,1] \to [0,1]^2$ is cont and onto (which is why it's called "space-filling").  Now I was able to show this myself by following Rudin's hint (a solution and some nice graphs may also be found [Here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~chr/104.S11/hw/104_spacef.pdf)). I should also remark that this construction is due to IJ Schoenberg
My question is how we can arrive at this fn g in the first place?  Here we are given a fn g and asked to show it satisfies certain properties (most importantly, the space-filling property), how can we "cook up this g from scratch"?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How familiar are you with the Cantor set?

Comment: I believe I'm familiar with it up to what has been described in Baby Rudin, for instance, that it's uncountable, perfect, has no "length", consists of base-3 "decimal" expansions using only 0's and 2's, etc.

Comment: Does Rudin show that there is a continuous surjection $C \to [0,1]$?

Comment: Peano's original paper is interesting to look at. Modern descriptions often use self-similar pictures, but it seems he made a point avoiding pictures, only using what I would term a "computational" or "recursive" description see http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0036&DMDID=DMDLOG_0013 and http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002252376 His paper is in French, but the math notation is easy to follow. I used his description to write a recursive computer program that generated the frames for the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaoCp08hznM

Comment: @DanielFischer: I do not believe he does :(

Comment: Pity, because that is what is used here. One maps $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n 3^{-n}$ to $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (a_n/2)2^{-n}$. That corresponds to $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{f(3^{n-1}t)}{2^n}$. Then one uses that $C\times C$ is homeomorphic to $C$ (one factor corresponds to the even-indexed terms, the other to the odd-indexed terms). So we take the splitting homeomorphism $C \to C\times C$, compose that with the surjection $C \to [0,1]$ in each factor, and continuously extend the surjection $C \to [0,1]\times [0,1]$ we thus obtained to the whole interval $[0,1]$. Brilliantly simple idea.